# s.replace is not a function while using sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to pass some attributes to a method throw `sequilize.literal` and I get this error.

This is my code :

```
include: [{
        attributes: ["id", "description", "latitude", "longitude", addValue(
        sequelize.literal("`subcategories->establishments`.longitude"),
        sequelize.literal("`subcategories->establishments`.latitude")), 'virtualColumn'],
        model: establishment, as: 'establishments',
        required: false
 }]
```

This is my method :

```
function addValue(value) {
    console.log(value)
    return value * 100;
}
```

Do I have the syntax wrong? (s.replace is not a function while using sequelize)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everyone who is having this trouble I was unable to call a function like that and having the sequelize.literal inside. This was the way I did it, hope it can help someone.

```
include: [{
                    attributes: [
                        "id",
                        "description",
                        "latitude",
                        "longitude",
                        [sequelize.literal(' (6371 * acos ( '
                            + 'cos( radians(' + latitude + ') ) '
                            + '* cos( radians( `subcategories->establishments`.latitude ) ) '
                            + '* cos( radians( `subcategories->establishments`.longitude ) - radians(' + longitude + ') )'
                            + '+ sin( radians(' + latitude + ') )'
                            + '* sin( radians( `subcategories->establishments`.latitude )))) '), 'distance']
                    ],
                    model: establishment, as: 'establishments',
                    required: false
                }]
```